# Problem removing event sources from FullCalendar (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Right then, I'm using [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) to display events from multiple sources, some local JSON feeds, others from Google Calendar. I've implemented a feature whereby a single calendar can be displayed / hidden when it's checkbox is true or false respectively.

I'm using this code to achive it:

```
$('#calendar_list input','#sidebar').live('click', function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")==true) {
        // display the calendar     
        var source = $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic");
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
    } else {
        // remove the calendar
        var source = $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic");
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source);
    }
});
```

This example if just to show / hide a Google Calendar feed, the problem is it never hides the calendar again... if I click the check box 10 times, (1=off, 2=on, 3=off, 4=on etc) it displays 5 versions of the same calendar.

[The documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/) doesn't really seem to give many clues and it seems this problem has plauged a few on the Google Project site for the project.

How to I remove an event souce?! *cries*

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right then, I've actually found the solution to my problem, I decided to look back over the Google Project issues and noticed that [someone had raised an issue](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=350&can=1&q=removeEventSource&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars) for the same problem I was having, now the documentation says:

> Source must be a reference to the original Array/URL/Function. Events from the source will immediately be removed from the calendar.

I thought this meant to remove a calendar I would have to use an identical source to the one I added, so if I added source `/getEvents.php` I would have to remove it in the same way, instead what it actually means is that I have to use the exact same source.

So I set the source as an item in an array (calendar id as the key) and then I can add / remove the calendar based on this, this has now solved the problem.

Comment: Ahh, good, I'm glad you figured it out... I was still scratching my head :P

Comment: Cheers, thanks for your help anyway, certain enlightened me to those two useful functions. Just seems the documentation isn't as clear as it could be.

Comment: OMG. Please...PLEASE let this be the solution i've been after. I was up from 1am till 4am last night working on this "duplicate bug". sob... I think to clarify things you should add to your answer code the solution you found ie, `var gcal = $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed(source); // the reference
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', gcal);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', gcal);`Implementing now fingers crossed...

Comment: i'm trying to implement this fix, where in the code do i specify the `var myFeedFull = $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed("http://www.somesite.com/feed.php");`? No matter where i've put the line it gets a javascript error. I tried in `$(document).ready(function() {`, in `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({` and outside completely. Thanks for any help. I've been pulling my hear out over this issue

Comment: My code is a little complicated to just slap up here, what JavaScript error are you getting and are you experiencing duplicated events?

Comment: Man u saved me, u are legend been trying to figure out this the whole day

Answer (score 1):

You should [rerender events](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/) after adding/removing a source, or maybe try to [refetch events](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/) if that doesn't work. That might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if I rerender the events nothing happens, if I refetch the events the Google calendar keeps adding itself :S

Comment: Just a follow up @fudgey, I've figured out my problem, see my answer. Cheers :-)