# Show/Hide multiple div classes independently based on checkbox value

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, checkbox, show-hide

I've seen several questions similar to mine, but I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm working on a calendar with JavaScript powered by FullCalendar using Google XML URLs. My objective is to show/hide events on the calendar based on a checkbox value corresponding to the events on the calendar. Such events are grouped by type (they're on separate Google calendars with separate XML URLs but are rendered on the same calendar display on the webpage) and have different div class names. I have 11 different classes total and need a way to toggle their visibility independently of the other classes based on a checkbox value.

I'm in the process of learning JQuery/JavaScript and hence much of it is still Greek to me. I found a solution that works for a single class, but is dependent on all of the other checkboxes' values if other checkboxes are present. This is the JS I'm using currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doInputs(obj){
 var checkbox = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked"); 
 var i =0, box;
 $('.className').fadeOut('fast');
     while(box = checkbox[i++]){
     if(!box.checked)continue;
     $('.className').fadeIn('fast');
     break;
     }
 }
</script>
```

And the corresponding mark-up:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="className" onclick="doInputs(this)"> Class Name Text
```

This works quite well; however, I can't figure out how to make it work with multiple div classes. Any suggestions?

Comment: So am I to understand that the "name" of the checkbox is the same as the "class" of the div that you want to fadeIn/Out?

Comment: Please make a JS Fiddle then i can try and help your- I know how to do it-i just dont have time to do all the code for you. Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a different solution, one that works much better and uses existing FullCalendar JS actions. Instead of using div classes and their class names as the determining factor of their display status, I used FullCalendar's removeEventSource and addEventSource actions to show/hide each of the 11 calendars being toggled.

The original JS is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092394/problem-removing-event-sources-from-fullcalendar-jquery). A little more picking around and I would have found this much sooner.

Thanks to those that commented and answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass class name of div along with JS function e.g.

```
doInputs(this,'classname')
```

and according to that class name you can toggle that class

E.G

```
function doInputs(obj,cc){ 
......
$('.' + cc).fadeOut('fast'); 
......
}
```